# ruby on rails model creation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

i am new to ruby.
When i am creating the model it gives the following error. Please resolve this issue.

```
noexec.rb:75:in `block in setup': undefined method `name' for ["hike-1.2.3", #<Gem::Specification name=hike version=1.2.3>]:Array (NoMethodError)

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `each'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `map'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:75:in `setup'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:114:in `check'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:121:in `<top (required)>'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:33:in `require'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:33:in `rescue in require'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.4.2/lib/rubygems_executable_plugin.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `call'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:50:in `block in run'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `each'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/hooks.rb:49:in `run'

from /home/rajesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:10:in `<main>'
```

Comment: whats was the rails generate command you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using this https://github.com/sstephenson/hike

Remove it from your project and start again - if the model gets created then problem is in the `hike` gem,

then try different versions of the gem, see on https://github.com/sstephenson/hike if there's a similar reported issue